# generate pair of uniformly random variables given a single uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Say we have $X \sim U(0,1)$, a standard uniform variable. I want a function $\{Y,Z\}=f(X)$ from $R$ to $R^2$ that gives us a pair ${Y,Z}$ such that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and both are $U(0,1)$. Does this exist? It seems like conjuring two random variables from a single one, which is counterintuitive, but I do know you can map injectively from R to $R^2$ so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Well...take the binary expansion of $X$ and then let $Y$ consist of the odd index entries, and $Z$ the even.  Thus if $X=.11011000011101\cdots$ we'd have $Y=.1010\cdots $ and $Z=.1100\cdots$

Comment: @lulu yeah that works! if you can put it in an answer i'll accept it. looking at the representation didn't strike me at first. it naturally follows you can generate countably finite unif randoms using a single one (considering bits at position i^n for each prime number i would do the trick)

Comment: Another popular method is the [Box-Mueller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

You can use the binary expansion of $X$ to create two, or even countably many, independent variables, all uniform on $[0,1]$.  To do $2$, for instance, just let $Y$ denote the binary number made from the odd digits of $X$, and $Z$ the binary number made from the even digits.

To make countably many, consider the (infinite) list of primes $\{2,3,5,7,11,\cdots\}$ and make one variable out of the digits in places $\{2, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots\}$, the second out of the digits in places $\{3, 3^2, 3^3, \cdots \}$ and so on.